# How to strip the full path using file info in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# programming.Please suggest me how to retrieve the fullpath but using only file.Name in my code as I only want to enter file name in my listBox not full path

My code is:

```
listBox1.DataSource = GetFolder("..\\video\\");

private static List<string> GetFolder(string folder)
{
    List<string> FileList = new List<string>();

    var allFiles = new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles("*.mpg", 
                                                    SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    foreach (FileInfo file in allFiles)
    {
        FileList.Add(file.FullName);             
    }    

    return FileList;  
}
```

Comment: do you need folder and files also

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInfo(path).Directory.FullPath
```

Your actual problem of your code is missing semi-colon for this line

```
var allFiles = new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles("*.mpg", 
                                                    SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

It should be

```
var allFiles = new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles("*.mpg", 
                                                    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Please give a few word summary atleast.

Comment: I'm afraid the missing semicolon is a result of an edit of the original question

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you want the FullPath as value but only the FileName displayed. To achieve this, you could use a List of `FileInfo`s containing both of these values and tell the ListBox, which member is the value and which one should be displayed:

```
this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.listBox1.ValueMember = "FullName";
listBox1.DataSource = GetFolder("..\\video\\");

Player.URL = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedValue);  // Instead of SelectedItem

private static List<FileInfo> GetFolder(string folder)
{
    List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();

    foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles("*.mpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
       fileList.Add(file); 
    }    

    return fileList;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Stephan but my problem is not resolved as when I am using your code it asks for a (;) on line var allFiles and after putting it error accurs which are as follows:Error 1 The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) and  Error 2 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'var' because 'var' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'...Please help its urgent!!

Comment: now the code worked but on debugging it shows Argument Exception was unhandeled :Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource. on line listBox1.DataSource = GetFolder("..\\video\\");

Comment: Thanks Stephan Now the code is running fine as my list box now shows the .mpg file names only not the fullpath but when I am trying to play these files with windows media player on my form using Player.URL = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem); the player is not able to play the file as its not getting the fullpath but previously it was playing the videos when full path was shown in the   listbox..plz help..

Comment: Once again :-) ... Use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`

Comment: I answered your other question that you posted today and then I noticed you created this question here before that.  @StephanBauer gave you a very good tip here, adding the FileInfo directly to the list instead of calling .ToString() but for some reason you did not apply that in your code and new question. I suggest you follow his and my advice, it will really help you. Also, you should come back and mark answers if they satisfy you

Comment: Thanks to you TimothyP and Stephen.Your suggestions helped me  a lot and I resolved my problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
 FileList.Add(file.FullName);
```

Please Change this line like below

```
 FileList.Add(file.Name );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  listBox1.DataSource = GetFolder("..\\video\\");

  private static List<string> GetFolder(string folder)
  {
        List<string> FileList = new List<string>();

        var allFiles = new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles("*.mpg", 
                                                SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        foreach (FileInfo file in allFiles)
        { 
              FileList.Add(file.Name);             
        }    

        return FileList;  
  }
```